# Making overflow go from the bottom

Tags: css

I have a css code:

```
.user_chat .chat{
    height: 425px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

My overflow start listing from the top, how to make it list from the bottom?

I tried to google some options but i did not find nothing, if some could help, i wood be pleased.

Comment: What you exactly want can you please describe with more details and with an example?

Comment: I have a chat on my web page, i need so my chat was starting from the bottom, not from the top.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` with `flex-direction: column-reverse`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Start. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. End.
</div>
```